# can I install cruisecontrol.rb in heroku?

Tags: heroku, cruisecontrol.rb

Can I deploy cruisecontrol.rb in heroku

cruisecontrol rb uses GIT and runs shell commands.

Would heroku let do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: No, you can't.

Heroku's stacks generally use a [read-only filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem), and even recent stacks with the new [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-isolation#ephemeral_filesystem) won't persist data among dynos or across dyno restarts. The lack of a writable filesystem with data persistence makes running continuous integration on Heroku a non-starter.